# How to parse xml using jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Hi I am trying to fetch xml data ..
Structure is like this :
....

```
<transport>
    <Journey>
    <JourneyPatternSection id ="JPS_13">
       <from> a</from>
       <to>b</to> 
    </JourneypatternSection>
        </Journey>
        <JourneyPattern id="JP_1_0">
                                <JourneyPatternSectionRefs>JPS_13</JourneyPatternSectionRefs>
                        </JourneyPattern>
        <VechileJourney>
        <JourneyPatternRef>JP_1_0</JourneyPatternRef>
                    <DepartureTime>17:10:00</DepartureTime>
    </VechileJourney>
</transport>
```

I have extracted JourneypatternId using jaxb but I am not able to get the departure time and to and from information as  journey pattern id has refrence in vechilejourney tag .

Comment: Have you followed the [JAXB Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/index.html)

Comment: yes i have followed but the tutorial only describes how to parse the xml not to manipulate

Answer (score 2):

Download trang.jar from http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang-manual.html
Go to the command prompt, 
To Convert your xml to xsd, type below command

```
java -jar trang.jar transport.xml transport.xsd
```

After converting your xml structure to xsd, and write below command,

```
xjc -p com.jaxb.test.xml.beans transport.xsd
```

Above command will generate java beans from your transport.xsd

After that you can unmarshall your xml as below

```
try
    {
        final JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Transport.class);
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        try
        {
            final Transport transport = (Transport) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new FileReader(TRANSPORT_XML));
        } catch (final FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (final JAXBException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Reference: http://shahpritesh.blogspot.in/2012/06/writing-and-reading-java-object-to-and.html

Comment: that everything has been taken care of ,my concern is how to manipulate the data that we will retreive suppose i get the id from jaxb ,this id is used as a refrence in the xml ;how to reach that block ,do we need dom parsing in that ?

Comment: you can xpath in jaxb. JXPathContext.newContext(this).iterate("//JourneyPatternRef[@id='JP_1_0']");